# Import all doesnot work

Tags: python, eclipse, import, bdd

I am trying to build a BDD test environment using `Behave` in `Eclipse`. Whenever I start with the `import` definition as `from behave import *` `Eclipse` throws the `import` warning.

Also, the decorators for `given`, `when` and `then` are marked as `undefined variables`.

Does anyone have any clue why are the `decorators` not imported?

Error message when using `from behave import *`

```
Unused in wild import: AmbiguousStep, StepRegistry, i18n, importer, json_parser, log_capture, matchers, model, names, runner, runner_util, setup_step_decorators, step_matcher, step_registry, tag_expression, textutil... others suppressed
```

Error message for decorators:

```
Undefined variable: given
```

Comment: can you add your error message?

Comment: added the error messages

Comment: "Unused in wild import" is a warning ;-) try to import explicit: e.g. from behave import given, when, then, step [Some hints about behave](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/behave)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First do:

```
import explicit
```

Then:

```
from behave import given, when, then, step
```

That should work, if it doesn't add a comment :)